# Birt, XML, Report Parameters, Data Sources

Tags: xml, parameters, dataset, datasource, birt

I'm using the **Birt Plugin** and I want to use an XML Data Source. I also want to use report parameters in the `xml` file.

An example of a query for a `JBDS` implementation with report parameters:

```
select COLUMN_NAME_1,COLUMN_NAME_2 from T_TABLE where COLUMN_NAME_1=?  and COLUMN_NAME_2=?
```

What would an example of an `xml` implementation with report parameters look like?

Comment: The ? represents the input parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is specified at [eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable2.5M7.php](http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable2.5M7.php)

If you scroll down you will see a title in purple called "XML Data Source Parameters." Under that header, it is described that in order to set parameters the following must be done:

1. Category must be set in the tags, those you wish to connect the parameters to, in the xml file.
2. If you click on edit data set and go to column mapping or row mapping, you can set the xpath expression to library/book/[@category="{?p1?}"], where p1 is the input parameter name.

Comment: try to elaborate answer to your question, not only provide a link.